# Unable to input text continuously in the fields without the need to click again

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

The issue of not being able to write more text in the fields without clicking again
here is my code

```
export default function login() {

    
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

    const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });

    const handleChange = (field) => (e) => {
        setFormFields({ ...formFields, [field]: e.target.value });
      };

   
    const EndAdornment=({showPassword,setShowPassword})=>{ 
        return( <InputAdornment position="end"> 
        <IconButton onClick={() =>setShowPassword( !showPassword)}>
        {showPassword ? <VisibilityOffIcon /> : <VisibilityIcon />} 
        </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>

)}      const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
           //mystyling here
        
    });

  return (
<Box className="user_login">
    <Box className="section_padding  bg-primaryBg">  
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
    <Box className="form_container rounded-xl bg-white border-2 p-10">
 
   <form className='mt-5'>               
                        <Box className="py-2">                 
                            <CssTextField required value={formFields.email}  onChange={handleChange('email')}   fullWidth id="email" margin='normal'/>
                            </Box>
                            <Box className="block md:flex align-middle justify-between items-center">
                            <Box className="py-2 w-full ">
                         
                            <CssTextField type={showPassword ?'password':'text'} value={formFields.password}  onChange={handleChange('password')}   required InputProps={{  endAdornment: <EndAdornment showPassword={showPassword} setShowPassword={setShowPassword}/>  }} fullWidth id="password" margin='normal' />
                            </Box>
                            </Box>
                        
                  </form>
    </Box>
    </Container>
    </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I have try to use material UI using custom styling but I am unable to write more text in field without clicking again i think its rendering again after each input

Comment: Please share a reproduction of your app (GitHub repo, or CodeSandbox) for debugging.